# Last() con datetime devuelve InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

estoy creando una aplicación con .net framework 4.7.0 y Entity framework core 3.1.25. La base de datos es un SQL server 2003.
Estoy intentando hacer una consulta sencilla de prueba:

```
 Context.Set<TestEntity>().Last(x => x.CreatedDate.Date.Equals(DateTime.Now.Date));
```

en la que me está devolviendo el siguiente error:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<TestTableEntity>
.Where(t => t.CreatedDate.Date.Equals(DateTime.Now.Date))
.LastOrDefault()' could not be translated.
```

El mismo error me recomienda reescribir la consulta en algo que sí pueda interpretar, pero pues hago exactamente el mismo query, pero con `FirstOrDefault()` y funciona perfectamente, ya intenté transformar las fechas a string, pero tampoco consigo pasar con éxito.

Sé que puedo "solucionarlo" rápidamente haciendo `.ToList().Last()`, pero no quiero llamar a todas las coincidencias del query para obtener sólo el último... ¿Alguien tiene una idea de qué puede estar sucediendo?

Comment: Necesitas todo el registro? o solo la fecha maxima por que de ser asi puedes hacer uso del max en vez de last o igual primero puedes filtrar como lo estas haciendo y tomas el ultimo

Comment: @EdgarVazquez la idea es obtener todo el registro...

Comment: Podrias hacer uso de dos pasos obtienes primero la fecha maxima y ya con la fecha vas a buscar el registro o como te dije puedes filtrar where (x=>x.CreatedDate==DateTime.Now.Date).FirsytOrDefault()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo pude "solucionar" de la siguiente manera:

```
var foundResults = Context.Set<Entidad>().Count(criteria);
            return Context.Set<Entidad>().Where(criteria).Skip(foundResults-1).Take(1).First();
```

Donde:
`Criteria` es el LINQ de búsqueda.
`Entidad` es la entidad de EntityFramework con la que estoy trabajando.

Básicamente, hago un count para saber cuántos elementos concuerdan con mi filtro. y despúes, al where, le digo explícitamente que quiero el último registro. No es lo más ortodoxo, pero de momento, soluciona mi problema. Saludos!

Comment: Bien ahí, una solución simple y elegante. ¡Sigue avanzando, da una alegría tremenda ver tu progreso bro! Saludos :D

Comment: muchas gracias hermano! un placer! :D